# Simple HTML nav buttons aren't displaying

Tags: html, css, nav

Okay so my nav buttons used to display, but now are not. I'm not using javascript or anything "fancy" such as that. In dreamweaver, and jsfiddle they display, however when I open the site via firefox/internet explorer, my nav buttons are ghosts. I've also validated the site through http://validator.w3.org/

JSFiddle Link:
https://jsfiddle.net/3c7yky0z/

Here are examples:

Dreamweaver:
[image: Dreamweaver Example]

jsfiddle:
[image: jsFiddle Example]

Firefox:
[image: Firefox Example]
Any ideas?

```css
    nav {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        margin-bottom: 1em;
    }
    nav a {
        padding: .25em 5em;
    }
    nav a:hover {
        font-size: larger;
    }
    header, section, footer, aside {
        padding: .5em
    }
    header {
        padding: 3em;
        height: 330px;
        margin: 0;
        background-color: #a39b90;
        position: relative;
        background-image: url(/images/CrystalCoastBanner.jpg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-image: url(../images/CrystalCoastBanner.jpg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
```

```html
    <body>
    <header style="text-align:center">
    <a href="http://pbernhardt.mydevryportfolio.com/wgd232/index.html"><h1> Crystal Coast Theater.
    </h1></a>
    <nav style="text-align:center">
    <a href="http://pbernhardt.mydevryportfolio.com/wgd232/index.html">Home</a>
    <a href="http://pbernhardt.mydevryportfolio.com/wgd232/event.html">Events</a>
    <a href="http://pbernhardt.mydevryportfolio.com/wgd232/ticket.html">Tickets</a>
    <a href="http://pbernhardt.mydevryportfolio.com/wgd232/contact.html">Contact us</a>
    </nav>
    </header>
```

Comment: Added my fiddle link

Comment: It's something to do with position. Try to inspect the elements in web tool and play around with css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this on your nav element:

```
nav {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

If you scroll down, you'll find it, right where that positioning would have it.

**[Demo sans those styles](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/3c7yky0z/1/)**

Regarding your comment, here's what I see in Firefox (and Chrome) at your original fiddle:

[image]

Comment: It doesn't even display them at the bottom on Firefox for me.

Comment: Now this is completely blowing my mind right now. It is displaying something completely different for me on my screen, but I will look into playing with the position element in the CSS for my nav. Thank you.

Comment: Protip: Explicit positioning is rarely needed with good layouts. It's often used as a crutch to solve problems that wouldn't exist with a simpler markup structure.

Comment: This site is being designed for an online course for school, so (almost) all of the code is coming from my course's instructions; hence the interesting topic choice of the site. However, I do thank you for your support on this matter. if I had enough rep, I'd +1 you.